# Rails group_by and in_groups_of error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

I have a list of organisations, grouped and displayed by their name, in alphabetical order. I want to display these across 4 columns for each letter, i.e.:

```
A
A... A... A... A...
A... A... A... A...

...

Z
Z... Z...
```

I have used the following code:

```
<% @organisations.keys.sort.each do |starting_letter| %>
    <div class="page-chunk default">
        <h6><%= starting_letter %></h6>
        <% @organisations[starting_letter].each do |organisations| %>
            <% organisations.in_groups_of(4).each do |column| %>
                <div class="one_quarter">
                    <% column.each do |organisation| %>
                        <%= link_to organisation.name, organisation_path(organisation) %><br />
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller:

```
@organisations = Organisation.all.group_by{ |org| org.name[0] }
```

But get `undefined method`in_groups_of' for #`for my troubles. If I change the code to`@organisations[starting_letter].in_groups_of(4).each do |organisations|`then I get a`NilClass` error.

What have I done wrong and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Try `organisations.in_groups_of(4, false)`
Without the `false`, it will fill in any empty spots in the last group with `nil`s, which means it will try to call `name` on `nil`.

Comment: Isn't that silly that this isn't the default behavior? Thanks.